# Hyperlink references to google scholar profiles do not work, using \href?

Tags: hyperref, hyperlink, href, google-scholar

Hyperlink references to google scholar profiles do not work, using \href

```
\href{https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=qc6CJjYAAAAJ&hl}{Albert Einstein}
```

Produces:

hl## Albert Einstein

Not a clickable "Albert Einstein that leads to https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=qc6CJjYAAAAJ&hl.

See larger example latex code below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{parskip}    
%other packages for formatting
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{geometry}

%tabularx environment
\usepackage{tabularx}

%for lists within experience section
\usepackage{enumitem}

% centered version of 'X' col. type
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 

%to prevent spillover of tabular into next pages
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newlength{\fullcollw}
\setlength{\fullcollw}{0.47\textwidth}

%custom \section
\usepackage{titlesec}               
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}

%CV Sections inspired by: 
%http://stefano.italians.nl/archives/26
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{10pt}{10pt}


%Setup hyperref package, and colours for links
\usepackage[unicode, draft=false]{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour,linkcolor=linkcolour}

%for academic icons
\usepackage{academicons}

%for social icons
\usepackage{fontawesome5}



\begin{document}

% non-numbered pages
\pagestyle{empty} 




\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} C @{}}
\Huge{Prof. Albert Einstein} \\[7.5pt]
\href{https://github.com/a-einstien}{\raisebox{-0.05\height}\faGithub\ a-einstein} \ $|$ \ 
\href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/albert-einstein-9b2753a3/}{\raisebox{-0.05\height}\faLinkedin\ Albert Einstein} \ $|$ \ 
\href{https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=qc6CJjYAAAAJ&hl}{\raisebox{-0.05\height}\aiGoogleScholar Albert Einstein} 
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

Comment: try without the `&hl` (or provide a proper test example)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle not completely sure what you meant. However, I have provided a more in depth example of the latex code.

Comment: Your URL ends in `&hl` which is not needed and removing it avoids the special `&`  ,  https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=qc6CJjYAAAAJ is the same page As I suspected, but you did not show, you had `&` in a `tabular`....

Comment: Welcome TeX.SE Martin David Grunnill. What David Carlisle meant is to use `\href{https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=qc6CJjYAAAAJ}{Albert Einstein}` (notice the absence of `&hl` and I just checked, it makes no difference: same page)

Answer (score 1):

You get the error

```
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \href@split.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.63 \end{tabularx}
```

After any error the PDF is not intended to be usable.

Here you can simply use

https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=qc6CJjYAAAAJ

as it links to the same page and avoids `&` In cases where you need `&` in the URL and you are in a context like `tabularx` where `\href` can not make `&` safe, use `\&` so

```
\href{https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=qc6CJjYAAAAJ}{\raisebox{-0.05\height}\aiGoogleScholar Albert Einstein}
```

or

```
\href{https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=qc6CJjYAAAAJ\&hl}{\raisebox{-0.05\height}\aiGoogleScholar Albert Einstein}
```